rsync performs checksum even when files have different sizes
I'm testing rsync on WSL with two local paths and I see when I use --checksum switch, it starts calculating ALL source files' checksums, even if target file has a different size that obviously indicates its checksum will be different! And even when target directory is totally empty!
rsync -avin --checksum /dir1/ /some-empty-dir

Also I've tried -W or --whole-file to disable delta transfer but problem still exists.
Also as I tested, rsync doesn't perform content-only check and when I rename a heavy file on the target (or move it to another directory keeping its initial name), it still removes it and copies the file with the initial name/path from source, therefore I can't really find a reason for this approach nor a way to ignore checksum in these cases.

Well, yeah. It's documented in the manual that it behaves that way when you use that switch.
